# Processing sequence with duplicates concurrently

Tags: scala, collections, concurrency, future

Suppose I've got a function `fab: A => B` , a sequence of `A` and need to get a sequence of pairs `(A, B)` like this:

```
def foo(fab: A => B, as: Seq[A]): Seq[(A, B)] = as.zip(as.map(fab))
```

Now I want to run `fab` concurrently using `scala.concurrent.Future` but I want to run `fab` only *once* for all duplicate elements in `as`. For instance,

```
val fab: A => B = ...
val a1: A = ...
val a2: A = ...
val as = a1 :: a1 :: a2 :: a1 :: a2 :: Nil
foo(fab, as) // invokes fab twice and run these invocations concurrently
```

How would you implement it ?

Comment: do you want to have duplicates in result seq as well?

Comment: Yes. The sequence of the first items of the results are the same sequence as the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def foo[A, B](as: Seq[A])(f: A => B)(implicit exc: ExecutionContext)
: Future[Seq[(A, B)]] = {
  Future
    .traverse(as.toSet)(a => Future((a, (a, f(a)))))
    .map(abs => as map abs.toMap)
}
```

Explanation:

1. `as.toSet` ensures that `f` is invoked only once for each `a`
2. The `(a, (a, f(a)))` gives you a set with nested tuples of shape `(a, (a, b))`
3. Mapping the original sequence of `a`s by a `Map` with pairs `(a, (a, b))` gives you a sequence of `(a, b)`s.

Since your `f` is not asynchronous anyway, and since you don't mind using futures, you might consider using `par`-collections as well:

```
def foo2[A, B](as: Seq[A])(f: A => B): Seq[(A, B)] = {
  as map as.toSet.par.map((a: A) => a -> (a, f(a))).seq.toMap
}
```